# How long do you remain unconscious in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

When you get hurt in multiplayer, how long does the "unconscious time" last (during which you can be reanimated unless a foe executes you)?

And how do you make it longer with the space key? Do you need to tap in quickly or to match the same rythm as text flickering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unconscious time lasts: 12 or 11 seconds depending on difficulty.

Maximum time is about 21, 20 and 19 depending on difficulty.

To maximize unconscious time you must tap in rythm with text flickering.

Source: http://steelgames.us/me3/#downed

Comment: Who'd have known - I've been mega-spamming the Space key all this time! They did a crappy job explaining the mechanic :/